# How to handle additional login attempts after user has logged in?

Tags: php, authentication, login-script

I have a login script which works but, I'm wondering how I should handle additional login attempts when the user has already logged in. The login page redirects to the home page if it finds that the user has already logged in.

However, if user has multiple browser tabs opened at the login page, login with one, then attempt to login again using the other browser tabs either with the same login or another login, how should I handle this two types of request?

To complicate things, I have a verification page which will also log the user in after user has been verified using the token. How should I handle this, if a user has already logged in?

For example, user A and user B both registered and both receives the token via email. They are both on the same PC, same browser, same session. User A verifies the token, then logs in successfully. User B, then verifies the token then logs in...? Wait user A has already logged in! What should I do with user A?

What would be the best practice here?

Comment: use **session** or **cookie**..Please post your login code so that i could help u better

Comment: @BhuvanRikka Hi, thanks for your comment, however I don't need a fix in my code, I just need to know what behaviour to achieve for additional login attempts on the same session. The code will just make it more complicated than what the question is asking.

Comment: The code which i've posted is pure javascript. So it is complicated. Using php,you can make it easier. Different frameworks has different ways for creating sessions

Comment: @BhuvanRikka I just realised that my question title does not contain the word PHP as intended. I only tagged it. Doh. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if user has multiple browser tabs opened at the login page, login with
>   one, then attempt to login again using the other browser tabs, how
>   should I handle this request?

Surely then the login session would be set and there would be no need to authenticate if it is a valid login again?

There are generally 3 methods to handle additional logins:

1. Ignore it, allow people to login in different locations at the same time
2. Kick the first session out when the 2nd session logs in. This often isn't the best solution, but it solves the problem of people closing their browser (i.e. not logging out properly) and then trying to login again in a new session and being told they can't.
3. Given the user an error saying they are logged in elsewhere. If doing this, make sure there is a time limit on an active login so that if someone does forget to logout somewhere, or their browser closes unexpectedly, then they are still able to log back in - they just have to wait a certain period of time.

Personally, I go with the 2nd option unless there are abnormal circumstances.

Comment: Hi I've updated the question to expand on this. What if the login is not the same, it's another login? Do I still kill the first session?

Should I make sure $_SESSION is empty upon successful login?

Comment: In that case I'd just throw an error if someone is already logged in and then tries to re-login or tries to verify a token. Throw an error telling them to logout of the current account if they wish to login / verify another.

Comment: Good call. Make the user accountable for their action. Thanks I'll mark this as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Personally when someone does a double login, in whatever way possible the person who logged in first gets logged out.

Why?

Bascially because if someone forgets to logout and leaves his computer. Returns to another computer and tries to login and can't login he gets really really really agry.

When a user logs in he logs in, all other users that are logged in on that computer or under the same account on another computer get logged out. To allow the user to always login to his or her account.

You could also just ignore this. You can let someone login with one account on several places at once, if that doesn't cause problems in your application. But we cannot determin that for you.

As for two different users trying to login on the same browser, I never let this happen, its also impossible in my applications because I use a cookie for this.

Comment: It seems that people are misunderstanding my question. Perhaps I should rephrase it a little better to assist others with similar question. It's not separate browser/session/location. Same session/location/browser. Just two users competing to login using the same session. Or practically one user with two accounts.

Answer (score 1):

**Using cookies:**

In login page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(document.cookie.split(";")[0].split("=")[0] != "")//the login page checks for cookies every time it loads.if the password and id are saved,it'll redirects to homepage without showing login page
        {
        window.location.href = "welcome.html";
        }

if(condition)//condition when username and password are valid
            {
                var uname=document.getElementById("zname").value;
                var pswd=document.getElementById("zpswd").value;
                if(document.getElementById("chkbx").checked) //Remember me checkbox (stores username and password until "logout" is clicked in homepage)
                {
                    document.cookie=uname+"="+pswd;
                    alert("You will be automtically logged in when you visit this page again" +uname);
                }



                window.location.href="welcome.html";
            }
</script>
```

In home page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function del_cookie(name)
            {
        document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
    }
    function signOut()
            {
        del_cookie(document.cookie.split(";")[0].split("=")[0]);
        window.location.href ="login_page.html"
    }
</script>
```

**So,the login page checks for cookies every time it loads. If the password and id are saved,it'll redirect to homepage without showing login page**

Comment: +1 to this as although it's not what I'm looking for, it is useful and I will use it when cookie gets involved in the mix (remember me)

Comment: @chrolli sure buddy ;). It'll surely help someday coz u cannot achieve everything using php. u hav to stick to basics at times